# i want to use socket.io v4 with flutter without socket-io-client package

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io

please guys I want another package as an alternative to socket-io-client because this package does not support nodejs socket.io version 4 and should support null safety

Comment: Did you try the build in `dart:io` package's `Socket`.

Comment: please tell me how use dart:io as socket.io client

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dart:io` build in package

```
import "dart:io";
import 'dart:typed_data';

// Client socket
void conntectToSocekt() async {
  String host = "http://localhost";
  int port = 3000;
  Socket clientSocekt = await Socket.connect(host, port);
  clientSocekt.listen((Uint8List event) {
    // data comming from the socket. 
  });
}
```

the `dart:io` package's Socket is not support in flutter web